# Is it possible to run Ubuntu 15.10 in a lxc container on an Ubuntu 14.04LTS host?

Tags: lxc

I did not find any hint about it...

Is it possible to run Ubuntu 15.10 in a lxc container on an Ubuntu 14.04LTS host?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to run an Ubuntu 15.10 container in a Ubuntu 14 host. Use the steps in [this site](/https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html).
The main change is when creating your container you need to specify the exact image to download by its code name (ubuntu 15.01 is "vivid vervet").

```
sudo lxc-create -t download -n u1 -- -d ubuntu -r vivid -a amd64
```

That and you are good to go. Remember a container is (just) a namespace as long as it is GNU/Linux.